# Disable Beacon monitoring on a condition in Application

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I have a working app which uses AltBeaconLibrary to detect beacons in the background using BootStrapNotifier as suggested here [How can I start / disable background monitoring for beacons at runtime with AltBeacon Library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588667/how-can-i-start-disable-background-monitoring-for-beacons-at-runtime-with-altb).

Unfortunately, I have some unforeseen issues and am now working on a switch to disable the beacon scanning all together temporarily. I am thinking about taking out Bootstrapnotifier completely from the app.My question is

> Can I leave my custom application still implement BootStrapNotifier even though i wont be using it (is it
>   safe?) and then wrap RegionBootstrap (in onCreate) in a condition.
>   Would this make sure that beacon scanning is not enabled at all until
>   my condition is true?

So that in the future i turn on the condition and beacon monitoring just works...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you suggest is possible, yes.  If the custom `Application` class implements `BootstrapNotifier` but the`RegionBootstrap` is never constructed, it won't hurt anything -- the `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` methods just won't get called.  So you can certainly put its construction inside a conditional block.

It should be noted that `RegionBootstrap` is really just a convenience wrapper around regular monitoring APIs.  So if your logic is complex, you may also be able to accomplish the same end more cleanly by conditionally creating the regular Monitoring APIs from inside the `onCreate` method.

Full disclosure: I am the lead developer on the Android Beacon Library open source project.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply @davidgyoung. I would certainly leave it there to keep my work intact. Just wanted to confirm a couple more things.   1) I am turning beacon monitoring on/off based on a condition (referenced one of your posts). Once i have `RegionBootstrap` setup, Is `beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region)` and `beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region)` sufficient to completely stop and later start the beacon monitoring in the background or do i need to handle any other parameters? I also heard there would be some time lag before beacons get noticed.

Comment: Sorry about the multiple questions. Just a couple things, I wanted to clear after reading the docs. thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you can use `stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion()` to stop monitoring any of the regions passed to `RegionBootstrap`,  and then you can call `startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion()` to make it monitor a new region.  The time it takes to start scanning depends on whether the app is in the background and the value passed to `beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. that helped!!